# Data consistency and native callback from java

Tags: java, java-native-interface, javacpp

I have Java code that calls a native function which fills results by invoking a callback method multiple times *before* it returns. The native code doesn't spawn any threads on its own. All java-native is handled by [javacpp](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacpp).
The outline looks like this:

```java
class Scanner {
    private final LinkedList<Long> matchedIds = new LinkedList<>();

    private final Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void call(int id) {
            matchedIds.add(id);
        }
    };

    public void scan() {
      callToNativeLib(handler);
      matchedIds.forEach(System.out::println)  // throws sometimes
    }
}


new Scanner().scan();
```

The problem is it sometimes (very rarely) throws:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read field "next" because "this.next" is null
    at java.base/java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.next(LinkedList.java:897)
    at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:74)
```

Why could it be? Almost like the list is made broken by callbacks coming from native code.

**EDIT:**
Got a `ConcurrentModificationException`. My assumptions must be wrong.

Comment: Why is ```matchedIds``` not part of the anonymous handler class? It seems to me like a bad idea to call a native library with side effects (although this may be unrelated to the issue at hand).

Comment: It's not my code. I would make it all within scope of `scan()` but I don't think it makes any difference.

Comment: I suspect my handler gets GC-ed.